# Switching from VS debugger to WinDbg

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, windbg

Given I have started a live debugging session by clicking the Play button in Visual Studio (<kbd>F5</kbd>) in order to launch the executable.

Say that I find an interesting situation which cannot be analyzed in Visual Studio but I know how to analyze it in WinDbg.

How would I detach Visual Studio and attach with WinDbg so that WinDbg is now the debugger?

I have tried:

- detaching VS, but that will of course continue running the application, which I don't want
- attaching WinDbg. Only one debugger can be attached. I'm not looking for a non-invasive attach of WinDbg.
- I'd not like to create a crash dump in VS and then analyze that in WinDbg. I would prefer continuing the live debug session.
- freezing the threads (interestingly they show up as unfrozen in a non-invasive WinDbg), but they will be unfrozen when detaching VS

Comment: That's of course not what I want. I updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how it worked for me:

1. Attach a WinDbg instance in non-invasive mode (<kbd>F6</kbd>)
2. Detach Visual Studio
3. Attach a new WinDbg instance in invasive mode (<kbd>F6</kbd>)
4. It will break automatically
5. Detach the non-invasive WinDbg (`.detach`)

Likewise you can transfer control back to Visual Studio:

1. Attach a WinDbg instance in non-invasive mode (<kbd>F6</kbd>)
2. Detach the invasive WinDbg (`.detach`)
3. Attach Visual Studio
4. Break in Visual Studio (press Pause)
5. Detach the non-invasive WinDbg (`.detach`)