# Cannot debug pid 11588 - An attempt to set a process's DebugPort or ExceptionPort was made but port already exists

Tags: memory-leaks, clr, windbg

My windows service crashing every alternate day. My process is getting bigger and bigger. So I am trying to find the memory leak by using CDB.exe command. [Command line version of WinDBG]

I am trying to periodically attach and detach the process, so I am executing below command in administrator mode to print out top heap memory consumers over 1000 bytes.

```
  cdb -pn MyWindowsService.exe -c ".loadby sos clr; !dumpheap -stat -min 1000; qd"
```

I am getting below prompt error message

> An attempt to set a process's DebugPort or ExceptionPort was made, but a port already exists in the process or an attempt to set a file's CompletionPort made, but a port was already set in the file or an attempt to set an ALPC port's associated completion port was made, but it is already set."

What does it actually mean?

**I have also tried using WinDbg**

[image]

Is it anything to do with Debug Diag rules? If yes, how do I resolve it?

This is different from [Switching from VS debugger to WinDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710102/switching-from-vs-debugger-to-windbg) because, here I am trying to address specific problem if we keep open the visual studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching from VS debugger to WinDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47710102/switching-from-vs-debugger-to-windbg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem usually occurs if the process is already being debugged. The other debugger could be Visual Studio, ProcDump or another tool.

I was able to resolve it by closing the visual studio and running the executable independently.